# Run docker container as same user as on host machine to access created files

Tags: docker

I'm running a Docker container on a remote host, mounting some host folders to the container.
Since the container is run as root, however, all the files I create on the host from within the container are also owned by root, and not by my user. I don't have sudo privileges on the host, so I can't simply change the files ownership back to my user.

I tried getting my host user and group IDs by:

```
USER_ID=$(id -u)
GROUP_ID=$(id -g)
```

and then running the container with:

```
docker run -u $USER_ID:$GROUP_ID -v ... image_name
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 0 (Operation not permitted)
   ...fail
```

I also checked various online tutorials (like [this](https://dev.to/izackv/running-a-docker-container-with-a-custom-non-root-user-syncing-host-and-container-permissions-26mb)) about creating internal user and groups in the Dockerfile, but it always seems to mess up something when I try to install other things in the container (Python and some deep learning libraries, mostly).
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: That `start-stop-daemon` error is odd, mostly in that I'd expect to see that from a full VM's init system but not a container.  What is running inside `image_name`?  You can in principle `docker run -u root -v "$PWD:/pwd" -it busybox sh` to get an interactive shell inside a container where the directory `/pwd` is the current host directory and fix permissions that way, but if you're not supposed to actually have that level of permission it might be impolite to use Docker to gain root.

Comment: I'm running a terminal in the container, so that I can launch some long processes manually and check how they go. Anyway, it seems I can fix my issue by following the tutorial I linked...I just have to install everything I need in the container as root user, and then create and switch to the non-root user at the end.